# Getting My GL_QUADS to show

Tags: java, opengl, static, while-loop, lwjgl

I want my program to make a quadrilateral every time there is a left click.
I am new to lwjgl and am trying to use the if-statement

```
    if(lClick == true){
drawQuad();
}
```

now, (from debugging) I know the if statement works so my error must be in my drawQuad() variable.

Here is my drawQuad:

```
public static void drawQuad(){
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity(); // Resets any previous projection matrices
    glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    //System.out.println("drawQuad Is Being Used");

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2i(c1, c2);
        glVertex2i(c1, c4);
        glVertex2i(c2, c1);
        glVertex2i(c2, c3);
glEnd();

}
```

My c1, c2, c3, and c4 integers are

```
        int c1 = Mouse.getX() + 25;
        int c2 = Mouse.getX() - 25;
        int c3 = Mouse.getY() + 25;
        int c4 = Mouse.getY() - 25;
```

all of these integers are under the

```
while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you updateing your varibles, like when you click are you saying

```
public void updateCords(){
    c1 = Mouse.getX() + 25;
    c2 = Mouse.getX() -= 25;
    c3 = Mouse.getY() += 25;
    c4 = Mouse.getY() -= 25;
}
```

if not the cords will stay the same from the moment the program 1st runs

Answer (score 0):

A common newbie mistake is to call OpenGL drawing functions from input event handlers. Depending on the framework used there might be no OpenGL context active in input event handlers.

Instead of drawing the quads directly you should append to some list or array, and in the drawing code draw quads according to the data in that list/array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int c1 = Mouse.getX() + 25;
    int c2 = Mouse.getX() - 25;
    int c3 = Mouse.getY() + 25;
    int c4 = Mouse.getY() - 25;
```

is it possible you aren't adding 25 to your integers? below might be a solution (appending the = operator). Sorry this is my first contribution.

```
    int c1 = Mouse.getX() += 25;
    int c2 = Mouse.getX() -= 25;
    int c3 = Mouse.getY() += 25;
    int c4 = Mouse.getY() -= 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL you have to redraw your entire scene every frame. Thus instead of drawing your quadrilateral once when the mouse is clicked, you should instead store the location of every quad (perhaps in an ArrayList?). Then each time your `draw` / `render` function is called you can draw every quad that has been placed.

As a side note, I recommend learning OpenGL 3+ instead of legacy OpenGL.